# Why Docker has two types Docker Engine

Tags: java, docker, jvm, containers, virtual-machine

As per Docker theory, it helps to make application layer, platform independent by putting "Docker Engine" in between (This layer marked in blue in below diagram).

[image]

This seems very similar to JVM concept. It helps to make Java, platform independent language.

**Questions -**

1. Why Docker has 2 types of Engines (Linux, and Windows Engine), then ?

**My understanding -**

1. This way, it violates the fundamental concept of "platform independent".

Can you help me to clear my understanding on this ?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I imagine the two engines are designed to operate on the two different OSes. Kind of like how you can't run a JVM built for Linux directly on Windows*, or the other way around. (*I'm not counting WSL :-) )

Comment: You can find some basic information here: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)). You shouldn't be considering Docker as "platform-independent" because it is os-level virtualization. Maybe you are referring to the key concept of docker that it makes it easy for developers to pack all the dependencies to an image and run it on different environments (development/staging/production) without having problems like "it works on my machine, why doesn't it work on yours?" or "it works locally but not on the production server".

Answer (score 2):

The platform independence is for the container wrapping the application not the engine itself.

The whole idea of Docker is to wrap the application with its dependencies so that it can be deployed on any machine where Docker is installed.

Docker started intially for Linux only distributions. It was then extended to allow users to run containers on Windows/MAC. This was achieved by deploying a mini Linux VM in the background when installing Docker on Windows/MAC. The Docker engine would then run in this Linux VM and all containers would also run there.

The reason for that is containers need support at the level of the OS kernel and initially only Linux had this support. Then big companies started realizing the advantages and the huge interest in Docker by the community. So Windows decided to do the neccessary OS developments to have a Docker engine natively running on Windows 10.

In short, the platform independence is from the perspective of the application container. A Docker container that runs on Linux can also run on Windows without any changes. This is very similar to the JVM which is specific to an OS however the same java application can run anywhere the JVM is installed.

Comment: Don't we need to change DockerFile  ? As, DockerFile may contain Linux kernel commmands. For example, ```RUN ls```.